# How to plot connected components in the format of community structure plot?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have the following `code` plotting community structure of random graph `g`. As one can see, the community structure plot presents a nice visual impact. I like to generate a similar plot for the connected components of `g` using `ConnectedComponents[g]`. `HighLightGraph` is showing individual vertices in a given component with the same color but this kind of presentation is not so useful for my purpose. I like to see the components linked to each other through binary links between the components.

```
SeedRandom[4];
g = RandomGraph[{30, 50}, DirectedEdges -> True];
gg = ConnectedComponents[g];
CommunityGraphPlot[g, CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray, 
Method -> "Centrality"];
HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, #] & /@ gg];
```

Thanks.

Comment: does `CommunityGraphPlot[g, gg, CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray, 
 Method -> "Centrality"]` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr: Yes, it gives what I want to see. In fact, your solution provides answers to several of my problems. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the second argument of `CommunityGraphPlot` to specify any community structure (not necessarily a partition of the vertex set).

Using `gg` as the community structure

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g, gg, CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image]

If you want to retain the layout of the original graph, you can use the function `blobF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66134/125) to highlight groups of vertices with blobs:

```
SetProperty[g, {PlotTheme->"IndexLabeled", ImageSize -> Large,
  Epilog -> blobF[g, RandomColor[Length@gg],gg, .1] }]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[g, {ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> blobF[g, RandomColor[Length@gg], gg, .05] }]
```

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble with `SelfLoops`. In my graph, there are many self loops which I do not want to see. How can you drop them out of the final graph view?

Comment: @Tugrul, does `SimpleGraph@g` help?

Comment: It works for adjacency matrix, though vertex names are removed, which I do not want.I have been struggling with this problem for a long time. When I plot a graph using `SimpleGraph` it drops the vertex names. I also tried  `SelfLoopStyle` and `SelfLoops` but no success. I have a weighted directed graph with vertex names. I simply like to keep the integrity of the graph but when plotting it I do not want to see the selfloops with vertex names kept.

Comment: @Tugrul,  maybe post a new question with an example?

Comment: Yes, I should post a new question. Thanks.

Comment: I was writing a new question but in the meantime I discovered an answer to my question about `SelfLoops`. Here is the code: `SeedRandom[1];
am = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 10}];
ag = AdjacencyGraph[am, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
vLabels = {1 -> AGR, 2 -> FIS, 3 -> CO1, 4 -> CO2, 5 -> MA1, 6 -> MA2,
    7 -> EGW, 8 -> CST, 9 -> WHS, 10 -> HOT};
SimpleGraph[ag, VertexLabels -> vLabels]`

Comment: With  version 12 updates, `SimpleGraph`  works fine (it retains vertex names, edgeweights...) so if  your adjacency graph has named vertices, that is, if you define it as  `ag2 = AdjacencyGraph[Values @ vLabels, am]`, then `sg = SimpleGraph[ag2]` retains vertex names: `VertexList[sg] == VertexList[ag2]` is `True`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have version 11 which does not support your simpler `code`. Thank you.