# Generating set partition diagrams

Tags: visualization, combinatorics

I recently came across a very nice illustration of set partitions on wikipedia (Partition of a set [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set))

I need to reproduce this diagram in order to modify some things, does anyone have a good starting code?

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the difference between what you show and what you want. Can you clarify? Here's some code for what you show: https://pastebin.com/evFXi3pE

Comment: clarified, thanks for the snippet

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ***I need to reproduce this diagram ...***

We can use the function `blobF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66134/125) to generate blobs around subsets:

```
ClearAll[blobF, fC, partition]
fC[pts_, size_: .04] := Module[{}, CommunityGraphPlot[Graph@{}, {}]; 
  GraphComputation`GraphCommunitiesPlotDump`generateBlobs[Automatic, {pts}, size][[2]]]

blobF[g_, cols_, coms_, size_: .04] := Thread[{cols, EdgeForm[{Gray, Thin}], Opacity[.25], 
        fC[PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ #, size] & /@ coms}];
```

and the function `partition` [from this answer by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8532/125) to generate set partitions:

```
partition[{x_}] := {{{x}}}

partition[{r__, x_}] := Join @@ (ReplaceList[#, {{b___, {S__}, a___} :> {b, {S, x},  a}, 
 {S__} :> {S, {x}}}] & /@ partition[{r}])
```

We first sort the output of `partition`:

```
partitions5 = SortBy[{-Length@# &, Max[Length /@ #] &}] @ partition[Range@5];
```

and use `blobF` on subgraphs of `CycleGraph[5]` corresponding to partition elements:

```
cg = CycleGraph[5, ImageSize -> 80, ImagePadding -> 12, VertexLabels -> "Name",
  VertexLabelStyle -> 10, VertexSize -> Medium, VertexStyle -> Black,
  EdgeShapeFunction -> None];

graphs = SetProperty[cg, {Epilog -> blobF[cg, RandomColor[Length@#], #, .07]}] & /@ 
   partitions5;

 Grid[Join[{{First @ graphs, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft,  SpanFromLeft}}, 
  Partition[Rest @ Most @ graphs, 5], 
{{Last @ graphs, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Slightly more streamlined approach to generate plot of an arbitrary collection of subsets:

```
ClearAll[boX, bloB, subsetsPlot]
boX[a : {_, _}, e_] := a + # & /@ Tuples[{-e, e}, {2}]
boX[a : {{_, _} ..}, e_] := Flatten[boX[#, e] & /@ a, 1]

bloB[x_, e_] :=  Switch[Length @ x, 1, Point @ x, 2, Line @ x,
   _, FilledCurve[BSplineCurve[#, SplineClosed -> True] & @@ 
       ConvexHullMesh[boX[x, e]][ "FaceCoordinates"]]]

subsetsPlot[n_, subsets_, size_: .1, o : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] :=
  Graphics[{Black, MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2[[1]], 14], 1.15 #] &, CirclePoints[n]], 
     PointSize[.02], Point @ CirclePoints[n], 
     RandomColor[], PointSize[0.07], Opacity[.5], Thickness[.075], CapForm["Round"], 
     bloB[CirclePoints[n][[#]], size]} & /@ subsets, o, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

***Examples:***

```
subsetsPlot[9, {{3}, {1, 2, 6}, {4, 5, 8}, {7, 9}}]
```

[image]

```
subsetsPlot[9, {Range[7], {3, 6}, {3, 4, 8}, {2, 5, 6, 9}, {8, 9}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Starting with @Szabolc code I ended up with something below. I needed to get some approximate formulas for moments by dropping higher cumulants. The font size ended up a bit too small but worked otherwise (is there an easy way to make all text parts larger?)

```
(* Converts Moments term to Cumulant term and visa versa *)

conv[a_Moment] := MomentConvert[a, "Cumulant"];
conv[a_Cumulant] := MomentConvert[a, "Moment"];

(* Get positions of every term involving moment or cumulant *)

termPositions[expr_] := (
   poses0 = Most /@ Position[expr, Moment];
   poses1 = Most /@ Position[expr, Cumulant];
   poses0~Join~poses1
   );

(* Convert all moment (or cumulant) terms in the expression *)

convDeep[expr_] := (
  MapAt[conv, expr, termPositions[expr]]
  )

col0 = ColorData["Pastel"][0.2]; (* moment *)
col1 = 
 ColorData["Pastel"][0.8]; (* cumulant *)
Clear[pic];
pic[obj_] := (
   content = obj[[1]]; (* Cumulant[{0,0,1,0}] => {0,0,1,0} *)

   pts = CirclePoints[Length@content];
   pts = RotateRight[pts]; (* i, j, k, l in counter-clockwise order *)

      labels = {"i", "j", "k", "l"};
   labels0 = labels[[;; Length@content]];
   activeIndices = Thread[content == 1];
   col = Switch[obj[[0]], Moment, col0, Cumulant, col1];
   pts0 = Pick[pts, activeIndices];
   labels0 = Pick[labels0, activeIndices];
   Graphics[{{FaceForm[col], 
      EdgeForm@Directive[col, Thickness[0.15], JoinForm["Round"]], 
      Polygon[pts0]}, {Black, PointSize[0.07], Point[pts]}}, 
    Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], FrameTicks -> None,
     PlotLabel -> StringJoin[labels0], ImageSize -> Tiny]
   );


visualize[expr_] := (
   poses0 = Most /@ Position[expr, Moment];
   poses1 = Most /@ Position[expr, Cumulant];
   MapAt[pic, expr, poses0~Join~poses1]
   );

(* Zeros out cumulant of order greater than k *)

zeroOutCumulant[a_, k_] := (
   If[a[[0]] === Cumulant && (Total[a[[1]]] > k),
    0,
    a]);

zeroOutMoment[a_, k_] := (
   If[a[[0]] === Moment && (Total[a[[1]]] > k),
    0,
    a]);

(* Truncate cumulant expansion at 2 *)
truncate[expr_] := (
   MapAt[zeroOutCumulant[#, 2] &, expr, termPositions[expr]]
   );

expr = Cumulant[{1, 1}];
visualize[conv@expr]
target = Moment[{1, 1, 1, 1}];
formula = 
 truncate[conv@
   target]; (* convert to cumulants and drop higher order terms *)
\
formula = 
 FullSimplify@
  convDeep[formula];(* convert back to moments *)
visualize[
 target \[TildeEqual] formula]
```

[image]

Comment: You can add `LabelStyle -> {FontSize->16}` to change the plot label size (or `Style[StringJoin[labels0], 16]`), you can use `ImageSize -> Automatic -> {75,75}` so that the size of each rectangle is the same, and you can use `BaselinePosition -> Axis -> Center` so that the axis of each graphic is lined up.

Comment: thanks...is there a way to get + signs to be bigger?

Comment: You could do something like `Style[visualize[target ≈ formula], 20]`?