# Visualizing set partition lattice

Tags: visualization, combinatorics

There's a cool visualization of set of all partition over 4 elements ordered by refinement, which makes it a lattice. Can Mathematica be used to generate these kinds of visualizations automatically? This lattice is used when converting between moments and cumulants, also known as Möbius inversion.

A related question dealt with visualizing individual entries in the lattice -- [Generating set partition diagrams](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207183/generating-set-partition-diagrams)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function `refinementQ[x, y]` returns `True` if partition `y` is a refinement of partition `x`:

```
ClearAll[refinementQ, oneElementRefinementQ]

refinementQ[x_, y_] := And @@ (Function[i, Or @@ (SubsetQ[#, i] & /@ x)] /@ y);

oneElementRefinementQ[x_, y_] := And[Length[y] == 1 + Length[x], refinementQ[x, y]]


partitions4 = SortBy[{Length@# &, Min[Length /@ #] &}]@(Sort /@ partition[Range @ 4]);
```

We can use `oneElementRefinementQ` with [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) with built-in layout `"MultipartiteEmbedding"`:

```
RelationGraph[oneElementRefinementQ, partitions4, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding",  
     "VertexPartition" -> Tally[Length /@ partitions4][[All, -1]]},
  VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> 600, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
  VertexShapeFunction -> (Inset[Framed[
   subsetsPlot["Point", .1, 14, AbsolutePointSize[9], 
         AbsoluteThickness[9]][4, #2], RoundingRadius -> 10, 
       Background -> White], #, {0, 0}, Scaled[.15]] &)]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use `VertexCoordinates` with custom coordinates:

```
vCoords = ScalingTransform[{1, 1/2}]@RotationTransform[-Pi/2]@
    GraphEmbedding[CompleteGraph[Length /@ GatherBy[partitions4, Length]]];

RelationGraph[oneElementRefinementQ, partitions4, 
 ImageSize -> 700, 
 VertexCoordinates -> vCoords, VertexSize -> Large, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
 VertexShapeFunction -> 
     (Inset[Framed[subsetsPlot[][4, #2], RoundingRadius -> 20, 
        Background -> White], #, {0, 0}, Scaled[.15]] &)]
```

[image]

Use `vCoords2` instead of `vCoords` where

```
vCoords2 = Join @@ MapIndexed[
    Thread[{If[# == 1, {0}, Subdivide[-1, 1, # - 1]], (1 - #2[[1]])/2}] &,
    Length /@ GatherBy[partitions4, Length]]
```

to get

[image]

Replace `subsetsPlot[]` with `subsetsPlot["Text"]` to get:

[image]

```
partitions5 = SortBy[{Length@# &, Min[Length /@ #] &}]@(Sort /@ 
     partition[Range@5]);

vCoords = ScalingTransform[{3/2, 1}] @ RotationTransform[-Pi/2]@
    GraphEmbedding[CompleteGraph[Length /@ GatherBy[partitions5, Length]]];

RelationGraph[oneElementRefinementQ, partitions5,  
 ImageSize -> 800, VertexCoordinates -> vCoords, VertexSize -> Large, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
 VertexShapeFunction -> 
      (Inset[Framed[subsetsPlot["Point", .1, 14, AbsolutePointSize[4], 
        AbsoluteThickness[6]][5, #2], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
      Background -> White, FrameMargins -> -5], #, {0, 0}, Scaled[.05]] &)]
```

[image]

Use

```
vCoords2 = Join @@ MapIndexed[
    Thread[{If[# == 1, {0}, Subdivide[-1, 1, # - 1]], (1 - #2[[1]])/(5 - 2)}] &, 
    Length /@ GatherBy[partitions5, Length]]
```

instead of `vCoords` to get

[image]

**Appendix:** Functions from [Generating set partition diagrams](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207183/generating-set-partition-diagrams) (`subsetsPlot` slightly modified):

```
ClearAll[partition, boX, bloB, subsetsPlot]

partition[{x_}] := {{{x}}}
partition[{r__, x_}] := Join @@ (ReplaceList[#, {{b___, {S__}, a___} :> 
   {b, {S, x}, a}, {S__} :> {S, {x}}}] & /@ partition[{r}])

boX[a : {_, _}, e_] := a + # & /@ Tuples[{-e, e}, {2}]
boX[a : {{_, _} ..}, e_] := Flatten[boX[#, e] & /@ a, 1]

bloB[x_, e_] := Switch[Length @ x, 1, Point@x, 2, Line@x, _, 
  FilledCurve[BSplineCurve[#, SplineClosed -> True] & @@ 
    ConvexHullMesh[boX[x, e]]["FaceCoordinates"]]]

subsetsPlot[vshape : ("Point" | "Text") : "Point", size_: .4, 
    ts_: 14, aps_: AbsolutePointSize[15], 
    at_: AbsoluteThickness[20]][n_, subsets_, o : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] := 
 Graphics[{Black, If[vshape == "Text", 
    MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2[[1]], ts], #] &, CirclePoints[n]], 
   {AbsolutePointSize[aps[[1]]/2], Point@CirclePoints[n]}], 
     RandomColor[], Opacity[.5], aps, at, CapForm["Round"], 
     bloB[CirclePoints[n][[#]], size]} & /@ subsets, o, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

Comment: Looks nice! BTW, lattice for size 4 is isomorphic to the hypercube, I wonder if pre-built embeddings can make this easier to understand -- `GraphData[{"Hypercube", 4}, "Graph", "All"]`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` gives the cleanest picture among the built-in layouts i have tried. Re `{"Hypercube", 4}`, I probably misinterpreted the picture in your question, because i don't see how how the partition lattice is  isomorphic to `{"Hypercube", 4}`.

Comment: You can see it for a smaller set. IE, partition lattice for sets of size 2 is isomorphic to {Hypercube, 2} -- vertical edges represent adding or removing first element, horizontal correspond to the second element

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, `GraphData[{"Hypercube", n}]` _is_ isomorphic to the Hasse diagram of  `SubsetQ` on _subsets lattice_  of `Range[n]` ; but I don't see how any graph on _set partitions_ of `Range[n]` can be isomorphic to hypercube[n] because the vertex counts are not the same.

Comment: Ah, you a are right